# Bind value to ng-switch in Angular template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular. I have a directive that displays the navigation:

```
(function(){
    angular
        .module('instaguideApp')
        .directive('navigation', navigation);

        function navigation(authenticationData){
            return {
              restrict: 'EA',
              templateUrl: '/common/directives/navigation/navigation.template.html',
              scope: false,
              link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
                scope.data = {
                    isLoggedIn: authenticationData.isLoggedIn
                };
              }
            };

        }
})()
```

navigation.template.html is:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a href="/" class="navbar-brand">InstaGuide</a>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar-main" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul ng-switch="{{data.isLoggedIn}}" class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/#about">About</a></li>

                <li ng-switch-default>
                    <a href="/#login">Login</a>
                </li>

                <li ng-switch-when="true">>
                    <a href="/#logout">Logout</a>
                </li>

                <li>Debugging Value: {{data.isLoggedIn}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a service which stores the login state of the user:

```
(function(){    
angular
    .module('instaguideApp')
    .service('authenticationData', authenticationData);

function authenticationData(){

    var auth = {
        isLoggedIn: false
    };
    return auth;
}
})();
```

Once I successfully log in, i set "isLoggedIn" of authenticationData to true. When this happens I want to show Logout in the navigation rather than Login. You can see I am using ng-switch in an attempt to achieve this.

When I login, the template receives that I have logged in because I can see that "Debugging Value: false" changes to "Debugging Value: true".

However, Login and Register still appear in the menu, as if ng-switch has not registered that it's value has changed. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: just fixed that, thanks

Comment: why the tiresome downvote?

Comment: Again, why the downvote? The downvotes in this community are becoming very very tiresome.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but that's probably because it's a very simple question, with a problem (clearly not [a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by the way) that can be solved just by reading the examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the parentheses in the ng-switch value:

```
<ul ng-switch="data.isLoggedIn" class="nav navbar-nav">
```

ng-switch is expecting angular expression as its value. So there is no need to wrap the value into double parentheses.